# Problem with QLogic 4062c HBAs on ESXi 4.0 U1

Tags: cisco, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

I have 2 x3650M2 servers with qLogic QLE 4062c iscsi hba (1 adapter per server). I'm performing initial setup on them. When I use the ESXi interface to set the IPs, it sets the IP, and 'Recent Tasks' shows that it's completed successfully. However a few moments later, the IP address on each interface will change back to 0.0.0.0, although the iscsi alias I have remains. I cannot ping these IPs, but my storage unit IPs do respond to pings, so I'm pretty sure the switch is OK. When I reboot the server and go into the iscsi bios, the IPs are set to the IPs I chose. For each HBA, I have each interface connected to 2 separate Cisco 3560G switches for fault tolerance.

This seems very strange to me, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are supposed to configure the iSCSI HBA's from the ESXi console? My previous experience with Qlogic was to set the IP adress in the HBA's BIOS, and then the LUN's would automatically be presented to the operating system at boot-time (when the QLA module boots), like any other HBA.

This was done on a Debian Linux server, so it should be the same for ESX(i).

Edit: Targets should be set up via the ESXi cli, but the IP adress is set via bios.